# Extent of ScriptEngineManage eval?

Tags: java, eval, scriptengine

just wondering how complicated an equation the eval() method of ScriptEngineManager can process.

Would it, for example, be able to handle:

(3+2(√(6)))

And, if so, how would I define exponents? Would simply

4^(2*3)

work?

Answer (score 0):

[`ScriptEngineManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngineManager.html) cannot evaluate anything.

It is a factory class for accessing various scripting languages, e.g.

- [JEXL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/) (expression language)
- [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/) (expression language)
- JavaScript (built-in)
- [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)
- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)
- [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/)
- ...

As for evaluating a simple expression, all the ones I listed can do that. Their syntax might differ slightly, especially for exponent (power).

Recommend JEXL or JavaScript.
Getting Groovy or Scala is overkill for your purpose.